# Eclipse - Prevent part from being resized

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

In my eclipse e4 model I have set a parts container data to 1800 so that it wraps the content. When I resize the plugin, the part will grow or shrink depending which obviously messes up the UI. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, or maybe an alternative method for wrapping a GridLayout row around the content without having to use the container data field?

Comment: What container are you using? It is the container that uses the 'container data' of the child parts.

Comment: Well I'm using a "Part Sash Container" which contains the parts. I'm not sure I follow what your saying?!

Comment: Part Sash Container uses the 'Container Data' from its children to determine the relative sizes of the parts it contains. It does not support fixed size children. The data just specifies the relative sizes of the parts, it is not a size in pixels or anything like that. It is very hard to a fixed size part.

Comment: Ah ok I get ya. So is there anyway then I can wrap a GridLayout row around its content. For instance I have an swt combo on a row in a grid layout, but when I launch the application the rows are quite big so this combo has lots of space above and below. Could this be that I may not be using the GridData correclty to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Show us your code and what you see.

Comment: Actually that won't matter at all Greg. I got a little confused just now, as wrapping the the grid layout content won't matter because its the part I want fixed not the content. As you mention it doesn't support fixed size children, so I'll just leave it as is. Thanks.